# How to build an hierarchical structure in Android?

Tags: java, android, hierarchical

I'm developing an Android App and one of its feature is that you can navigate through a file server system. I have to build it from an XML file and I can get from it:

Every item with its own ID and its parent ID. Note: I also can consult every item separately with its ID and get its XML.

My idea is to build a Map where item has: id, parent_id and title. Insert every item with its own data. And each time my App has to consult the current folder, make a server consult to see its children and show it but I think its very redundant each time I would refresh the current folder or go back from it.
Maybe I should use a different structure data to save it (tree or something) where I can get children and parent and save everything from the beginning and then just consult parent and children to show current folder and go back from it.

I ask for any idea or some code source example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should use a tree, yes.

Each time you fetch this XML data, merge it into your current tree.

That way, you can easily maintain information from the past, and in a way which is consistent with how you are displaying and using it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be 2 levels of tree. The second level should be subfolders/files in the current viewing folder. You should never need to wait for a read when you explode a folder. When u explode a folder you should read all subfolders of the subfolders in the current viewing folder.

Thread sync will only be a corner case when someone opens folders really fast.

Comment: I'm really a newbie using Trees and I'm not sure how to do it. 
Can I add nodes and refers them to its parent and not to its children? I'd be pleased if there is any example code to do this kind of tree.
Thanks